# Zeros of $x^n - 2x^{(n-1)}+1 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Other than $x=1$, is it possible to find definite solutions to $x^n - 2x^{(n-1)} + 1 = 0$ for any integers $n>3$, or must the zeros always be approximated?

Comment: By "definite solution" you mean a closed-form algebraic solution in terms of the coefficients, I presume?

Comment: I have very good *approximations* of the largest root when $n$ starts to be large. But, to get any answer or help, please show us some work (even if, at a poin, you are stuck. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Peter, does this line in the answer to the linked question mean that there's no solution by radicals for any n > 5?
"So  contains a five cycle and an element with a cycle decomposition equal to the product of two 2-cycles. It follows  contains 5 and  is not solvable. Consequently,  will not be solvable by radicals."

Comment: Thank you, Claude; it's great to be here. I must confess I don't understand most of what I encounter here, but I still manage to learn a thing or two.

Comment: Yes it does but only for the example the answerer was using. Thus there is no *general* solution.

Comment: Is it for the lagest root ? If yes, is it "close" to some number ? Please, write your thoughts.

Comment: @PeterPhipps. But we can be so close to the solution by simple approximations.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, the solution I'm most interested in is the one that approaches 2 as n grows larger, but I thought it'd be best to pose it as a more general question. The problem came about as I was playing with Fibonacci type sequences, increasing the number of prior terms that are summed. As you're aware, for the Fibonacci sequence, the ratio of a(k+1) to a(k) as k goes to Inf is the golden ratio. I was curious what the ratio would be if a(k) = a(k-1) + a(k-2) + ... + a(k-n). The ratio approaches 2 as n grows larger, and I wondered if determining the exact values is possible.

Comment: Exact not but very good approximation. For example, for $n=5$, with a minimum effort, I have $x=1.927562124$ instead of $1.927561975$ and we can do much better

Comment: Have a look AT thé other post where I wrote an answer